# Adding metadata to ERC721 tokens

Tags: go-ethereum, erc-20, erc-721

could the metadata inn ERC721 be altered after issuing a token ?
    I want to create an contract allowing people changing the Token metadata content (on the tokens purchased in ICO).

Comment: if you are asking about technical possibility , then yes, you are the one who is programming the contract, so you can output from a `metadata` call even a pseudo-random number. btw, `metadata`  is optional, not a requirement.

Comment: I am treating metadata as added value, just trying to determine whether I can overwrite it. Do you have an idea what is the metadata weight limitation in erc721 ?

Comment: Haven't seen any size limitations in the standard specification of 721. But I am not fully understanding what are you trying to achieve. Maybe its worth detailing this in the original question. Because 721 tokens are non-fungible, i.e. each token is unique and has different price.  However the ICOs are offering fungible tokens (like EOS token for example) , these tokens have the same price for the entrie `totalSupply`. So I guess your idea of offering metadata on purchased tokens in an ICO is conceptually flawed.

Comment: I am thinking if I am able to alter the metadata, after deploying the contract.

Comment: I am trying to make an example for you but Remix IDE is broken at the moment. Please ping me if this is fixed // https://github.com/ethereum/remix-ide/issues/1531#issue-361785565

Answer (score 2):

Metadata of a non-fungible ERC-721 token are hosted on a public HTTP address. The content of this metadata JSON file can be changed. ERC-721 standard does not prevent you to add smart contract logic for changing token's URI.